# Eclipse and "Installation failed due to invalid APK file"

Tags: android, eclipse

I am combining `OpenCV` with `tess-two` to make an Android OCR application. It worked perfectly well with `OpenCV4Android` + custom JNI OpenCV libraries, until I started importing `tess-two` library. It compiles but does not install:

```
[2015-08-02 14:43:02 - OpenCV Tutorial 2 - Mixed Processing] Installation failed due to invalid APK file!

[2015-08-02 14:43:02 - OpenCV Tutorial 2 - Mixed Processing] Please check logcat output for more details.

[2015-08-02 14:43:02 - OpenCV Tutorial 2 - Mixed Processing] Launch canceled!
```

Other posts suggest it's library and reference errors. Indeed, it can install again when I remove `..\tess-two` in `Properties->Android->Library`. Also the `tess-two` library is compiled correctly, because I sueccesfully compiled and an example project.

And here is the logcat.

```
08-02 14:46:07.775: D/AndroidRuntime(14699): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
08-02 14:46:07.775: D/AndroidRuntime(14699): CheckJNI is OFF
08-02 14:46:07.785: D/dalvikvm(14699): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
08-02 14:46:07.795: D/dalvikvm(14699): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
08-02 14:46:07.805: D/dalvikvm(14699): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
08-02 14:46:07.805: D/dalvikvm(14699): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
08-02 14:46:07.835: E/cutils-trace(14699): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-02 14:46:08.005: D/AndroidRuntime(14699): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
08-02 14:46:08.015: D/zipro(9906): Zip: EOCD not found, /data/local/tmp/OpenCV Tutorial 2 - Mixed Processing.apk is not zip
08-02 14:46:08.015: D/asset(9906): failed to open Zip archive '/data/local/tmp/OpenCV Tutorial 2 - Mixed Processing.apk'
08-02 14:46:08.015: W/PackageParser(9906): Unable to read AndroidManifest.xml of /data/local/tmp/OpenCV Tutorial 2 - Mixed Processing.apk
08-02 14:46:08.015: W/PackageParser(9906): java.io.FileNotFoundException: AndroidManifest.xml
08-02 14:46:08.015: W/PackageParser(9906):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method)
08-02 14:46:08.015: W/PackageParser(9906):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:522)
08-02 14:46:08.015: W/PackageParser(9906):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlResourceParser(AssetManager.java:478)
08-02 14:46:08.015: W/PackageParser(9906):  at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parsePackageLite(PackageParser.java:787)
08-02 14:46:08.015: W/PackageParser(9906):  at com.android.defcontainer.DefaultContainerService$1.getMinimalPackageInfo(DefaultContainerService.java:174)
08-02 14:46:08.015: W/PackageParser(9906):  at com.android.internal.app.IMediaContainerService$Stub.onTransact(IMediaContainerService.java:110)
08-02 14:46:08.015: W/PackageParser(9906):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
08-02 14:46:08.015: W/PackageParser(9906):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
08-02 14:46:08.015: W/DefContainer(9906): Failed to parse package
08-02 14:46:08.025: W/ActivityManager(455): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/OpenCV Tutorial 2 - Mixed Processing.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11"
              android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>
```

to `AndroidManifest.xml` in both the project and the `tess-two` library. Everything worked.

Comment: An even more comprehensive testing shows that it is mandatory to set `android:minSdkVersion` correctly (or compatibly). I've set all to `android:minSdkVersion=9` and left out `android:targetSdkVersion=15` only in the APK application. It still works.